# How to add preview column in magento grid?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add a Column in grid with 'preview' text. Like in image :

[image] When I am over text with mouse I want to display a html page. The html page it is tacked from database(BLOB type).

**RENDERER:**

```
 public function render(Varien_Object $row)
            {
               //grid is filled with data from custom table page(id, title, html_code-BLOB)
                $aId =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
                $a = Mage::getModel('page')->load($aId);

               //HtmlCode is a column from database that contains BLOB html page
                $sourcecode = $a->getHtmlCode();

            if(isset($sourcecode))
        {
            $value='<a href = "" value="">preview</a>';
        }

        return $value;

    }
```

Comment: you can use a custom renderer for your column and in that you can fetch a html page from database and show on hover as you like  for your reference you can see http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

Comment: I use a renderer ...but I don't know how to fetch html page and show it on hover .

Comment: can you please show the code of your renderer

Comment: Updated! PLease look at my question.

Comment: Sorry it is a little messy